Запрос к файлу, исполнение(отдача) содержимого другого файла
В продолжение вопроса:
Динамический формировать robots.txt
AddType application

Через данное правило, возможно назначить исполнение фала как php. К примеру txt файлы, будут читаться как php файлы.
Трудность в том, что так устанавливаем правило глобально на все txt файлы сайта.
Вопрос в том, быть может возможно адресное задать иcполнение конкретного файла? Или скажем отдать содержимое другого при обращение к такому та url, к файлу robots.txt...?

RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots.php [L]```
